# Running rust sqlx migrations locally with docker-compose

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, rust-sqlx

I'm working through Zero to Prod in Rust and I've gone off script a bit. I'm working on dockerizing the whole setup locally including the database. On `ENTRYPOINT` the container calls a startup script that attempts to call `sqlx migrate run`, leading to the error `./scripts/init_db.sh: line 10: sqlx: command not found`.

I think I've worked it out that because I'm using `bullseye-slim` as the runtime it doesn't keep the installed rust packages around for the final image, which helps with the build time and image size.

Is there a way to run sqlx migrations without having rust, cargo etc installed? Or is there a better way altogether to accomplish this? I'd like to avoid just reinstalling everything in the `bullseye-slim` image and losing some of the docker optimization there.

```
# Dockerfile
# .... chef segment omitted
FROM chef as builder
COPY --from=planner /app/recipe.json recipe.json
# Build our project dependencies, not our application!
RUN cargo chef cook --release --recipe-path recipe.json
# Up to this point, if our dependency tree stays the same,
# all layers should be cached.
COPY . .

ENV SQLX_OFFLINE true
# Build our project
RUN cargo build --release --bin my_app
FROM debian:bullseye-slim AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -y \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl ca-certificates \
&& apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends postgresql-client \
# Clean up
&& apt-get autoremove -y \
&& apt-get clean -y \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/my_app my_app
COPY configuration configuration
COPY scripts scripts
RUN chmod -R +x scripts
ENTRYPOINT ["./scripts/docker_startup.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml` looks like below

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    image: my_app
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@postgres:5432/my_app
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: You could do something like `cargo install sqlx-cli` then `COPY --from=builder $HOME/. cargo/bin/sqlx-cli sqlx-cli`. I haven't tested it but something like this should work.

Comment: @pigeonhands that appears to have done the trick. Want to drop it in an answer and I'll mark correct?

Comment: Ive updated my answer to add an alternative solution that does not require sqlx-cli if that is of interest.

Comment: @pigeonhands: I like the do it in code solution. It avoids the headache of my last 20 min getting the configs into the env right.

but also: your general answer is correct for "avoiding extraneous things in mutipart docker builds", but in this sqlx related case we want to copy `sqlx` not sqlx-cli`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install `sqlx-cli` with cargo install in your build stage

```
cargo install sqlx-cli
```

then copy it over to the deployment stage with

```
COPY --from=builder $HOME/.cargo/bin/sqlx-cli sqlx-cli
```

---

Or you can run the migrations when your application starts with the [migrate!](https://docs.rs/sqlx/latest/sqlx/macro.migrate.html) macro

```
sqlx::migrate!("db/migrations")
    .run(&pool)
    .await?;
```